# When I try to run a java class in IntelliJ,nothing comes out even though it has been successfully compiled and run

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compiler-errors

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEXNF.png)

Did I mess up with the JV machine?

Comment: can you show your code ?

Comment: screenshot please?

Answer (score 0):

Try right click the class which contains main method and click run in the right click menu. If this works, problem is with the default main method in your program. change it.